# How to suppress a error when `render` have a argument `nil` in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `render` method in a view to call partial template like this:

```
<%= render @post if @post.present? %>
```

Is there a way to write like this?

```
<%= method_like_try(:render, @post) %>
```

So that I don't need to check the presence of `@post`.

If it is not implemented in Ruby or Rails, I'll just stick first style.

Comment: How about `render @posts || (nothing: true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, there is nothing wrong with

```
<%= render @post if @post.present? %>
```

It's already concise. Any attempt to shorten it will effectively cause the opposite effect.

```
<%= method_like_try(:render, @post) %>
```

Is less readable, and hides the intent of the rendering. There are a couple of possible improvements I can suggest, instead of hiding the logic into that method.

1. You can still reduce the line into

   ```
   <%= render @post if @post %>
   ```

   A `nil` object evaluates to false.
2. The other improvements is to catch the fact that `@post` is nil before. For instance, where is `@post` coming from? If it's a show action, you can easily use a bang-method to raise an exception if the value is nil. Or you can use a before filter

   ```
   class MyController

     before_filter :find_post

     def show
       render @post
     end  

     def find_post
       @post = Post.find_in_someway
       @post or head(404)
     end
   end
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can define it in the `application_helper.rb` :

```
def method_like_try(method, object)
  send(method, object) if object.present?
end
```

But you should choose a good name to be as readable as your first line.

Comment: I like the name `render_if_present` for this.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a version like the second option. The first is probably a better option as it is more readable and clear as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
render @posts || (nothing: true)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got a error `syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
...ppend=( render nil || (nothing: true) );@output_buffer.safe_...`